# Using variable from set_fact in roles within same playbook

Tags: variables, ansible

I'm stuck with using variable from tasks within roles in Ansible playbook. My playbook is following:

```
- hosts: server.com
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        private_ip: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
      when: "item.startswith('10.')"
    - debug: var=private_ip
  roles:
    - role: check-server
      server_ip: 10.10.0.1
      client_ip: "{{ private_ip }}
```

When pleybook is ran -debug shows correct IP inside the variable private_ip, but I can't make client_ip (from roles block) to get private_ip content. client_ip remains always undefined.

What sorcery can I apply here to have client_ip=$private_ip?

Answer (score 2):

`tasks` are executed after `roles` are applied.

Change `tasks` to `pre_tasks`.

---

<sup>Besides, using `set_fact` in a loop is not the best practice. If you get the value you want, that's ok, I believe you verified it. But you should rather use `(ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | select("match", "10\..*") | list)[0]`.</sup>

Comment: That's it! Thought that playbooks were executed as they were read, my bad!

Comment: Playbooks are executed in the order, because playbooks are lists of plays. Plays, on the other hand, are dictionaries and dictionaries are unsorted. They are interpreted according to key (`pre_tasks`, `roles`, `tasks`) names; the writing order does not matter.